# How to center the text inside the anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

I have arranged the anchor tag with text with borders.
I want to make the text to center inside the block. 
I have tried padding, margin left, float but nothing is working.

```css
body {
                background-color:black;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                
            }
            .title{
                height: 17%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0%;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 2rem;
                color: white;
            }
            .subjects{
                color: white;
                width: 28%;
                height: 7%;
                border: 2px solid white;
                font-size: 2rem;
                border-radius:20px;
                margin-top: 86px;
                margin-left: 8px;
                text-align:center;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            
            .maths{
                margin-left: 24%;
                margin-top: 41px;
            }
           
            .maths a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                border: 2px solid white;
                padding: 4px;
                padding-right: 140px;
                font-size: 2rem;
                border-radius: 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
                vertical-align:middle;
                display: inline-block;
                
            }
             .physics{
                margin-left: 24%;
                margin-top: 41px;
            }
           
            .physics a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                border: 2px solid white;
                padding: 4px 103px;
                padding-right: 206px;
                font-size: 2rem;
                border-radius: 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
                vertical-align:middle;
                display: inline-block;
                
            }
             .chemistry{
                margin-left: 24%;
                margin-top: 41px;
            }
           
            .chemistry a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                border: 2px solid white;
                padding: 4px;
                padding-right: 169px;
                font-size: 2rem;
                border-radius: 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
                vertical-align:middle;
                display: inline-block;
                
            }
```

```html
<div class="title">
             <h1>Syllabus</h1>
        </div>
    <div class="subjectsList">
        <div class="subjects">
             Syllabus
            <span class="triangle"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="maths">
            
            <a href="mathsinfo.html" target="_blank">
                <!--<img src="images/maths.jpg" height="50px" width="50px" alt="Mathematics Icon">-->
                    Mathematics</a>
        </div>
        <div class="physics">
            
            <a href="physicsinfo.html" target="_blank">Physics</a>
        </div>
        <div class="chemistry">
            
            <a href="chemistryinfo.html" target="_blank">Chemistry</a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

that physics text must be at middle.Can anyone help me out to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the padding (left and right padding to half of what you had for right padding):

```css
.physics{
                margin-left: 24%;
                margin-top: 41px;
            }
           
            .physics a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                border: 2px solid black;
                padding: 4px 103px;
                font-size: 2rem;
                border-radius: 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
                vertical-align:middle;
                display: inline-block;    
            }
```

```html
<div class="physics">
            
            <a href="physicsinfo.html" target="_blank">Physics</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: the border is also getting increased

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but the overall size of the element stays exactly the same

Comment: I mean when i am doing it in my code, with the text movement,border line is also increasing its size

Comment: no, that's impossible, it's 2 px, and that doesn't change unless you have another setting in another, overwriting CSS rule which you didn't post.

Comment: just to make sure, have you erased your `padding-right: 206px;`?

Comment: No, you haven't - erase it - the right padding is included in the combined padding I have in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

remove padding-right:206px; add text-align:center

```
.physics a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                border: 2px solid black;
                padding: 4px 0px;
                font-size: 2rem;
                border-radius: 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
                vertical-align:middle;
                display: inline-block;    
                text-align:center;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove margin-left from `.physicsc` and  padding-right from `.physics a` and set

```
.physics {       
   text-align: center;
}
.physics a {
  width:30%; // or anything you need
}
```

Also check out [centering guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).